# Expose ID in serializer.validated_data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a nested relationship, and when I need to expose the ID of a serializer in the serializer.validated_data, but this is not working, here I will show an example of my serializer:

```
class AdsImagesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   image = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True,allow_empty_file=True)

   class Meta:
       model = AdsImages
       fields = ('id','image','ads',)



class ADSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    adsImages = AdsImagesSerializer(read_only=True,many=True)

    class Meta:
      model = ADS
      fields = ('id','headline','description_1','description_2','display_url','final_url','mobile_url','adsImages','advertiser',)


class CampaignSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    advertiser = AdvertiserProfile(read_only=True,required=False)
    ads = ADSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
      model = Campaign
      fields = ('id','name','type','start_date','end_date','locations','budget','land_page','keywords','CPM','CPC','description','commission','pay_off','ads','advertiser',)

    def get_validation_exclusions(self, *args, **kwargs):
        exclusions = super(CampaignSerializer,self).get_validation_exclusions()

        return exclusions + ['advertiser']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ads_data = validated_data.pop('ads')
        campaign = Campaign.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for ad_data in ads_data:
            ADS.objects.create(campaign=campaign, **ad_data)
        return campaign
```

This doesn't work, and everywhere i see this like an answer, don't know why ?

> OrderedDict([(u'name', u'Demo Campaign'), (u'type', u'PayPerSale'), (u'locations', u'Macedonia'), (u'budget', 10), (u'land_page', u'http://www.test.com'), (u'keywords', u'k1,k2,k3,k4'), (u'CPM', 1), (u'CPC', 2), (u'description', u'demo description'), (u'commission', 10), (u'pay_off', 20), (u'ads', [OrderedDict([(u'headline', u'Demo headline'), (u'advertiser', )])])])

Comment: id = serializers.ReadOnlyField() put it in your serializer.

Comment: @AndreyShipilov not working

Comment: Do you need ID of the serializer or the nested serializer?

Comment: @AndreyShipilov of the nested serializer

Comment: Then you need to make the “id=YourNestedSerializer” to your actual serializer. Basically you need to use make two serializers and use the nested one as an ID for your parent one.

Comment: @AndreyShipilov I updated my question now